# trying to put a 120mb message on activemq using producer

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm trying to put a 120mb message on activemq using producer. But I'm getting this error

> failoverTransport:273 - Transport (tcp://localhost:61616) failed,
>   attempting to automatically reconnect java.io.EOFException

I have increased my java heap load but the error still persists.
I've been searching but I cant seem to find a solution.

Comment: more information would be needed for anyone to give you an answer

Comment: So I looked at the activemq logs and realized that i was exceeding the frame size of 100MB. I increased it to 512000000 when I run the producer I get this error "Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format."